# Unable to access custom table cell variables

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1, with Swift. I have a Table View which was working fine for a normal type of cell, but it's started displaying errors after I changed it to use a custom cell. I made a Table View Cell in the storyboard, made a Cocoa Touch Class file, MyCustomCell, which is a subclass of UITableViewCell, and set the custom cell in the storyboard to use this class, in the Identity inspector. I wired a text field I put into the custom cell in the storyboard to the MyCustomCell.swift file as a variable called someData.

The problem occurs here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as MyCustomCell
        cell.someData!.text = "testing"
        return cell
}
```

Come runtime, the "testing" line gives me a **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** error, assuming that I manually registered the cell class in viewDidLoad, like this:

```
tableView.registerClass(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

If, instead, I never register the class, instead putting "Cell" in the storyboard as the Restoration ID for the custom cell, I get the same exact error nil error message, but on the "let cell =" line instead of the "testing" line.

The MyCustomCell class wires the someData variable and has init, awakeFromNib, and setSelected shells but nothing else.

I'm not really sure how to fix this. Maybe I need to create a nib for the custom cell or something? Any help would be appreciated.

(By the way, I'm using Core Data to store entities for each table cell, but that's not shown here, since I'm only concerned with getting custom cells working right now.)

Comment: The reason for that to happen is that `cell.someData` is nil, and you are force unwrapping it. Check that you are properly initializing that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Restoration Id (Identity Inspector) instead of the Indentifier (Attributes Inspector) in Interface Builder.

Comment: You're totally right, I was confusing those for some reason. I'm still not sure why the attempt with registerClass() didn't work though -- I guess it didn't want to override my given storyboard Identifier (which I did set to something, I just forgot about it and later confused it with the restoration ID).

Comment: I think your cell could have been going through a different init (`initWithFrame` instead of `initWithCoder`). When a cell gets loaded through interface builder, it connects the weak IBOutlooks through that method I believe. 

When a cell is created in code, that varible might not have been connected.

Answer (score 1):

When `UITableView` is instantiated from storyboard calling 
`registerClass(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` causes problems. You need to give reueseIdentifier in storyboard in attributes inspector.

Comment: I did give a normal identifier but I forgot about it and was using the restoration ID for some reason instead.